# Tensorflow profiling for non-model computations

Tags: gpu, profiling, tensorflow2.0

I have a computation which has for loops and calls to Tensorflow matrix algorithms such as `tf.lstsq` and Tensorflow iteration with `tf.map_fn`.  I would like to profile this to see how much parallelism I am getting in the `tf.map_fn` and matrix algorithms that get called.

This doesn't seem to be the use case at all for the [Tensorflow Profiler](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/profiler) which is organized around the neural network model training loop.

Is there a way to use Tensorflow Profiler for arbitrary Tensorflow computations, or is the go-to move in this case to use NVidia tools like [`nvprof`](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-nvprof-your-handy-universal-gpu-profiler/)?

Comment: nvprof can't be used for this sort of use case (and it is deprecated, so depending on what type of hardware you have it wouldn't work anyway)

Comment: What do you recommend that works?  I have NVidia GPU on Linux.

Comment: You are asking about calculating the degree of parallelism that a GPU accelerated Python framework is achieving. That would imply you need to instrument and analyze at a Python interpreter, host binary and GPU level simultaneously. That isn't a conventional GPU profiling use case and I am not aware of any tools which can do that. Certainly not anything supplied with the CUDA toolkit

Comment: The profiler instruments calls to CUDA kernels and works with any program that calls the CUDA libraries.  It doesn't matter what the interpreter layer is doing.  It matters how busy the GPU is.  Profiling matrix computations on a GPU is a conventional use case.

Comment: How "busy" the GPU is isn't the same thing as "how much parallelism I am getting". How much parallelism you are getting is the ratio of serial computational work to parallel computational work. You need to measure both if you want to do as you describe in your question, i.e https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law

Comment: Please read this gist for the kind of GPU profiling information which is availabe for a Python program using nvprof and nvpp: https://gist.github.com/sonots/5abc0bccec2010ac69ff74788b265086

Comment: I am fully aware of what nvprof can measure and what its output looks like. The problem is that that information isn't useful for answering your question. Seeing a stream of low-level GPU operations doesn't tell you how much parallelism those tensorflow routines are achieving. They don't run on the GPU. They offload some fraction of their work to the GPU, via some intermediate GPU accelerated libraries. Unless you know what that fraction is, you are no closer to answering your question. And the GPU profiler doesn't do that

Comment: So what would you say is the use case for nvprof, nvvp and nsight?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the `nvprof` and `nvvp` and `nsight` tools I was looking for are available as a [Conda install of cudatoolkit-dev](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/cudatoolkit-dev).  Uses are described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sonots/5abc0bccec2010ac69ff74788b265086).